# How can i optimize my number animation javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```js
const ratingcount = document.querySelectorAll('.ratingcount');
const totalratingcounter = ratingcount.length;

var stopNow = totalratingcounter

countEach()
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
      countEach()
})

function countEach() {
    $('.ratingcount').each(function() {
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false' && stopNow != 0) {
            //console.log($(this).text())
            //console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
            stopNow = stopNow - 1;
        }/* else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }*/
    })
}

function showOnScreen(target) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(target).offset().top)
      return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function numberAnimate(target) {
    var $this = $(target);
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ratingcount">7.8</span>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<span class="ratingcount">7.8</span>
```

What this code do?

1. It make number animation
2. Start the number animation from 0 and complete it to a specified number in `ratingcount` class
3. If the number is showing on screen, it do animation.
4. If the number is not showing on screen, it do animation only on scroll, so the user can see it.
5. It do animation only 1 time on scroll (If you scroll again, then it will not work)

Now, sometimes, when the Internet is slow or something like that, the script do not work or stop at a random number. I tried my best to optimize it, can someone help me to optimize it more, so it works everytime, under all or most of the conditions.

Comment: Script will either run or not run, there should be no effect on what the script does of internet connection that is used.

Comment: does your script wait with execution until the DOM has been loaded?

Comment: I am not Javascript expert, it took me really a lot of time to make it @TimothyGroote. . I don't know, what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @11thdimension Sometimes, the script stop to a random number. (Like 2.3, while the original number is 8.6)

Comment: Your code snippet works well when internet is slow -- I used Chrome's Network debug panel and simulated GPRS environment, it works fine.

Comment: It's doing that because you're not setting the number value at the end. At the end of the animation you can set the final value.

Comment: @shaochuancs Oh, then i guess, It do not work because i have a lot of PHP code in my page, and the page loads all the PHP before actually sending data to user

Comment: Their must be a reason, why it do not work sometimes. 

And @11thdimension i do not understand, sorry, what you mean sir?

Comment: @JoshPoor If this topic focus on "number animation", what is the purpose of these `on('scroll'...`, `showOnScreen(...` code? Can you remove these code and minify the problem?

Comment: It do animation when the number is on screen bro? @shaochuancs

Comment: @JoshPoor If this "animate when number is on screen" logic is removed, does the problem still exist?